# Another version of Erdös-Ginzburg-Ziv theorem

Tags: number-theory

I came across this version of the **EGZ** **theorem** used in different proofs:

> Any set of 2**N**−1 integers, has a subset of size exactly **N**, such that
>   the sum of elements of that set is divisible by **N**.

However the first version of the theorem is as stated in this link: [Erdös-Ginzburg-Ziv theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Erd%C3%B6s-Ginzburg-Ziv_theorem)

I can't understand if this version is correct or not, because it feels like that this one is just a wrong interpretation of **EGZ** **theorem** and misunderstood as **EGZ** itself.
Plz tell me that is this theorem wrong?
And if its rigt then how can I deduce it from **EGZ theorem**?

Comment: When you replace the condition that the elements be in $Bbb Z_m$ with arbitrary integers, then the result that the sum of the elements in that subset is $0$ is replaced with the sum being divisible by $m$, since $0=km$ in $\Bbb Z_m$. ($N$ and $m$ are the same here)

Comment: I don't have any issue for the variables N or m!!
The difference between the who theorems is that the original version asks us to choose elemnets from Zm 
But the theorem I mentioned here says you can choose elemnts from the set of integers and get the result.

Comment: My confusion is that can we proof EGZ theorem for any integers not necessarily in Zm={0, 1,2, ..., m-1}
That is can we choose integers greater than m and still get the same result, as this version of he theorem states?

Comment: Yes, this is my point: in the link you provide the theorem asserts that the sum of the elements is **equal to $0$**, but in the statement you give you assert that the sum of the elements is **divisible by $N$**. In the link, the setup involves the elements being in $\Bbb Z_N$, and in your setup the elements are just integers. But every integer is a multiple of an element in $\Bbb Z_N$. So the assertions are different as well as the setups.

Comment: "equal to $0$" in $\Bbb Z_N$ is equivalent to "divisible by $N$"

Comment: Ok now I get the point! Thank you